# Find biggest value in a sequence

Tags: c

I wrote the program that came up with the first n terms of the hofstadter q sequence. (1,1,2,3,3,4...)

Now I have to come up with the biggest term of this series. I wrote this code, but it didn't work.
(for exapmle I want to first 5 term of this sequence.1 1 2 3 3 that is okay.Now I find biggest value of this array so 3)
 I have to use `int(arr[ ],int index,int maximum)`. How can I fix it?

```
}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation to make your code readable. What exactly means "it didn't work". Please [edit] your question and show the input you used, the expected output and the actual output and/or error message.

Comment: Please, edit your question to show [a complete, minimal and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  It's important you show also not only what you expected, but also what your program shows. actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int maximum=arr[0];
```

Here, you assign `maximum` to `arr[0]`. At the moment you assign the value, `arr[0] = 0`, so `maximum` is always equal to `0`.

You have to assign `maximum` to the return value of `fm` function:

```
maximum = fm(arr,0,n);
```

Comment: yes, it fix it thanks but I only get one mistake .If the biggest term is the last term, it doesn't print it.For example ,if 7 terms are to be entered ,1 1 2 3 3 4 5 sees the largest term of the array as 4.

Comment: change `if(index>maximum-2)` to `if(index>maximum-1)`, will fix it ?